# type deduction guide on variadic template function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I found some solutions for type deduction guides for variadic classes but not for functions like I intent to use.

First, this works as expected:

```cpp
template<typename... T>
void print(T&&... args) {
    ((std::cout << args),...);   
}

int main() {
    print("Hello ", "World! ", "The answer is ", 42);   
}
```

gives:

```cpp
Hello World! The answer is 42
```

As 2nd, I want to constraint the template argument count using C++20 concept as:

```cpp
constexpr auto MAX_ARGS = 4;

template<typename... T> concept ArgsT = requires(T... args) {
    // count must be even
    requires (sizeof...(T)) % 2 == 0;
    // the count is limited by arg count size
    requires (sizeof...(T)) / (2*MAX_ARGS+1) == 0;
};

template<ArgsT... T>
void print(T&&... args) {
    ((std::cout << args),...);   
}
```

and the problem starts with `constraints not satisfied ...`

So, next a type deduction guide shall help here, and here I am:

```cpp
template<ArgsT... T>
void print(T&&... args) {
    ((std::cout << args),...);   
}

template<typename... T>
auto print(T&&... args) -> template<typename T> auto print<T...>(T&&...);

int main() {
    print("Hello ", "World! ", "The answer is ", 42);   
}
```

gives error `error: expected a type`, see [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/4KboczWEM)
Clang gives some hints, but finally I wasn't able to write the deduction guide with this. How does it look so that the constraint function `print(...)` compiles, or even rejects due to violated concepts? It must compile on the Big 3 compiler.

Comment: deduction guides are only for types, ie classes, not functions.

Comment: **fwiw:** The only way to satisfy the constraint `a/b == 0` is to have  `a == 0`. I'm not sure it was your intention (or maybe I misundertood your contraints, I'm not used to C++20 concepts)

Comment: @Fareanor With integer division as long as `b > a` then the result will be `0`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh right, I'm so dumb XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template<ArgsT... T>` is incorrect, `ArgsT` only applies to a *single* type, that is, it only checks whether `ArgsT<T>` is satisfied, so it will never be satisfied. You should use `requires`-clause for this

```
template<class... T>
  requires (sizeof...(T) % 2 == 0) && 
           ((sizeof...(T)) / (2*MAX_ARGS+1) == 0)
void print(T&&... args) {
  ((std::cout << args),...);   
}
```